# How to find on which line tensorflow error is?

Tags: python, tensorflow

First of all, I want to mention that I am not asking for a solution to the error I am getting. I understand the meaning of it, but I want to know where I am getting it.

So, I am trying to train a custom TensorFlow model with jupyter notebook and after running the cell with `fit` method, I receive the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_80/513728415.py in <module>
     12 # remove `.take` when training on the full dataset
     13 
---> 14 model.fit(    train_dataset.take(1), epochs=epochs,    callbacks=callbacks_list,    verbose=1,
     15 )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    915       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    916       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 917       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    918     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    919       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3038        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3039     return graph_function._call_flat(
-> 3040         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3041 
   3042   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1962       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1963       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1964           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1965     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1966         args,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    594               inputs=args,
    595               attrs=attrs,
--> 596               ctx=ctx)
    597         else:
    598           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[node gradient_tape/FCOSLoss_3/LessEqual_12 (defined at tmp/ipykernel_80/2642055955.py:19) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_725115]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node gradient_tape/FCOSLoss_3/LessEqual_12:
 FCOSLoss_3/strided_slice_14 (defined at tmp/ipykernel_80/2419517512.py:84) 
 FCOSLoss_3/Max_1 (defined at tmp/ipykernel_80/2419517512.py:78)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

It is clear that traceback doesn't point to the exact location of my error, instead, it points to the line with `model.fit` and I am not able to see on which line I get the error. Still, the last few lines of the error message contain the number of lines, but I am not able to make sense of it. So, how can I find that line?

Comment: I would check the shape of a single input in your dataset and compare it with what your model expects.

Comment: @Priyatham, thanks for the suggestion, but I am not interested in the actual solution to the error. I am interested in finding the line

Comment: Interesting question! if error is pointing at `model.fit(), model.compile()`, it means we need to check all the defined parameters within these function including model definition. Along with this if we can check `traceback error`, specially at the bottom line of traceback error like `(ImportError, ValueError or InvalidArgumentError)`, gives us a better clue about the error.